# slider and number-input box controling the same number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is get the Slider Value  "sliderStatus" to appear in a number input box that can also change the value.

for example, if the slider is set to 199 and the customer wants to select 200 quicker, he can either enter the value in the box, or adjust with + or- or any other way.

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="1" step="1" style="margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; width:90%;" />
<br />
<br />Slider Value = <span id="sliderStatus">1</span> 
<p id="demo"></p> 


<script>
    $("#slider").on('change',function() {
    var selectedQty = $(this).val();
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);


    var itemTotal = 0;
     switch (true) {
        case (selectedQty <= 2) :
            itemTotal = 28 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 5) :
            itemTotal = 26 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 15) :
            itemTotal = 24 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 30) :
            itemTotal = 22 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 60) :
            itemTotal = 20 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 100) :
            itemTotal = 18 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 200) :
            itemTotal = 16 * selectedQty;
            break;  
        case (selectedQty <= 500) :
            itemTotal = 15 * selectedQty;
            break;       
        default:
            itemTotal = 14 * selectedQty;
            break;
    }

    $('#demo').text(itemTotal);
});  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will let you do the desired behaviour:

```
 //code for the input box

$('#sliderval').on('input', function() {
   var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();

    $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});

//code for the slider itself

$("#slider").on('change',function() {
    var selectedQty = $(this).val();
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
   //update the value of the input box
     $('#sliderval').val(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});  

//code for calculation

function calc(selectedQty) {

  var itemTotal = 0;
     switch (true) {
        case (selectedQty <= 2) :
            itemTotal = 28 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 5) :
            itemTotal = 26 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 15) :
            itemTotal = 24 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 30) :
            itemTotal = 22 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 60) :
            itemTotal = 20 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 100) :
            itemTotal = 18 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 200) :
            itemTotal = 16 * selectedQty;
            break;  
        case (selectedQty <= 500) :
            itemTotal = 15 * selectedQty;
            break;       
        default:
            itemTotal = 14 * selectedQty;
            break;
    }

    $('#demo').text(itemTotal);


}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7Ltrthj/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your time but I still couldn't make it work, I'm a beginner when it comes to coding and I think I took on more than i can chew.. I don't know exactly how to adjust the HTML part for the input box to show up. Thank You!

Comment: I added a JSFiddle link. You can see it working there - https://jsfiddle.net/v7Ltrthj/2/ 

I also did some updates so that the values update everywhere.